# accessing model from controller, is it a good way?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

i came across few blogs and forums and found this way of interacting with MODEL class from controller using LINQ to SQL

is it a proper way to access ?

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using MvcApplication1.Models;

    namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
    {
         [HandleError]
         public class HomeController : Controller
         {
              public ActionResult Index()
              {
                   var dataContext = new MovieDataContext();
                   var movies = from m in dataContext.Movies
                        select m;
                   return View(movies);
              }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For small-time projects and tutorials this is just fine and the recommended approach.

Small tip: You could wrap the `MovieDataContext` in a using statement which takes care of closing the connection and releasing resources:

```
using (var dataContext = new MovieDataContext())
{
    // query...
}
```

Keep in mind when using this, you can't lazy-load properties in your view anymore since the data context is closed when the object is sent to the view. So a query like `movie.Director.Name` won't work, unless you eager-load it.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that should be the standard way of using the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessarily bad, but you can improve on it by applying well known patterns and best-practices, i.e. layering, repositories, etc.

Ideally, it is good to keep the controller as thin as possible and delegate all database operations or whatever logic required on the lower levels, like a service layer for instance.